# wordpress portfolio and blog

Tags: image, wordpress, blogs, portfolio

Hello all im new to wordpress and i want to make a portfolio & blog site, i have a design but i dont know how to create the portfolio where i can show images and then click on the images so it get bigger.

do you guys have a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want make that gallery with Wordpress, I'd suggest using some plugins such as [Lightbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-2/). Please read also [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Photoblogs_and_Galleries) about photoblogs and galleries.